# Unexpected Output from code snippet - Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a code snippet and it is

```
List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
mylist.add("ren");
mylist.add("rahul->RC");
mylist.add("arun");
String sr = "rahul->RC";
String sr1 = "rahul";

for ( int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++ )
{
    if(mylist.get(i).contains(sr))
    {
        System.out.println(mylist.get(i)+" CONTAINS "+sr);
        mylist.remove(mylist.get(i));
        System.out.println("Inside : "+mylist);
        mylist.add("again"); 
        break;
    }
    if(mylist.get(i).equals(sr1));
    {
        System.out.println(sr1 +" EQUELS " +mylist.get(i)); 
        mylist.remove(mylist.get(i));
        mylist.add(sr);
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println("Final Output => "+mylist);
```

And When I run this code I got the Output as

```
rahul EQUELS ren
Final Output => [rahul->RC, arun, rahul->RC]
```

I wondered when i saw this output. How could `rahul EQUELS ren` this happens?
I couldn't figure out the problem? Please help me on this problem.

Comment: You are using two if conditions. During the second value both if condition is success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a semi-colon after your 2nd if statement:

```
if(mylist.get(i).equals(sr1));  // Remove the semi-colon
```

The semi-colon marks the end of `if` statement, and the following block, is just a local block, which will always be executed.

Answer (score 1):

That's classic: **remove the semicolon** after  `if(mylist.get(i).equals(sr1));`
The semicolon terminates the if statement (no block), and the following code block is then unrelated to the condition (you can have blocks anywhere in your code).

The code

```
if (condition);
{
  doSomething();
}
```

is the same as

```
if (condition) 
{
  // nop
}
{
  doSomething();
}
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, please don't [approve suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2763764) using backticks for emphasis, but reject or improve them - see e.g. [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88) why

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: good point, I wasn't aware of this issue, I'll be more cautious from now on. Thanks for the hint, I appreciate that :)

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any wonder.`if(mylist.get(i).equals(sr1));` second If ends without body. so next to if statement(`{...}`) will be execute every time but as you used `break` it executes once and break out of the loop.

```
if(mylist.get(i).equals(sr1));  // semi-colon makes the wounder :)
```

Answer (score 1):

Removed the semicolon. Execute the code below .  Due to the semi colon , the statement just after the statement will be executed always and EQUELS will be printed .

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    mylist.add("ren");
    mylist.add("rahul->RC");
    mylist.add("arun");
    String sr = "rahul->RC";
    String sr1 = "rahul";

    for ( int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++ )
    {


        if(mylist.get(i).contains(sr))
        {
            System.out.println(mylist.get(i)+" CONTAINS "+sr);
            mylist.remove(mylist.get(i));
            System.out.println("Inside : "+mylist);
            mylist.add("veendum"); 
            break;
        }
        if(mylist.get(i).equals(sr1))
        {
            System.out.println(sr1 +" EQUELS " +mylist.get(i))
            mylist.remove(mylist.get(i));
            mylist.add(sr);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}